# iPhone OCR doesn't recognize all the captured images text, But can recognize the predefined Text images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ocr

I have implemented a **business card reader image using ocr api** by follow the link/ tutorial

http://tinsuke.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-compile-and-use-tesseract-3-01-on-ios-sdk-5/

It can scan the text of some *`screen shots of UIalert views / table views. and some images having text`* like follows.

**Can recognize text on this image:**

[image]
[image]

*`[Airoplane mode wi-fi vpn ratch data sounds brightness general wall paper]`*

but when i capture business card it returns some special charecters and numbers. some times recognized if it is very very clear and big text in captured image.

**Can NOT recognize text on  follow like  images**

[image]
[image]

*`[ xas $- 432 *7 5$#2 $@@#%^ ^&* I( WQ#$  follow like√ √dg @ ]`*

why how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tesseract library is open source library. I don't think it is that much accurate.OCR gives best results for image more than 150 px resolution with black and white image .The image which you are capture with the camera of iPad or iPhone is saved with 72px that tesseract cannot give best results.If you are more interested then there are some paid libraries with good accuracy you can try out some :[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062755/ocroptical-character-recoginition-libraries-for-iphone)